# How to change Link color in Navbar upon clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change Link (A) color in the Navbar upon clicking and also if I navigate to another Link (B) color should return to default for Link(A).

```
links.forEach( a=>{ //Its Color Changes But I Want All The Others To Be In Default Color 
    a.onclick = () => {
        a.classList.add("active");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event to each element then on click on link perform add/remove of class.

```
var navElements = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      //looping through each anchor element
      navElements.forEach(function(element){
           //adding click event on each anchor element
            element.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                 //stop default behaviour
                 e.preventDefault();
                 //select current active element
                 let active = document.querySelector('.selected');
                 active?.classList.remove('selected'); //remove class  
                 this.classList.add('selected'); //add class to current click element
      });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
links.forEach(a=> {
    a.onclick = () => {
        links.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove('active'));
        a.classList.add("active");
    }
})
```

Comment: Is it because this works that it's been hated by haters?